# How do I parse datetime data using the .striptime() method?

Tags: python, pandas, datetime, for-loop

I am attempting to parse the datetime data in a df using pandas datetime module. I am however constantly running into the same error. I believe that my strftime syntax codes are correct but I still keep getting errors.

```
potus = pd.read_csv('potus_visitors_2015.csv')


import datetime as dt

date_format = '%m/%d/%y %H:%M'

for i, row in potus.iterrows():
    start_date = row['appt_start_date']
    start_date = dt.datetime.strptime(start_date, date_format)
    row['appt_start_date'] = start_date
```

But I am returned with the following error:

```
ValueError                                Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-259-fa3f6f4c8c4b> in <module>
      5 for row in potus:
      6     start_date = row[2]
----> 7     start_date = dt.datetime.strptime(start_date, date_format)
      8     row[2] = start_date
      9 

~\anaconda3\lib\_strptime.py in _strptime_datetime(cls, data_string, format)
    575     """Return a class cls instance based on the input string and the
    576     format string."""
--> 577     tt, fraction, gmtoff_fraction = _strptime(data_string, format)
    578     tzname, gmtoff = tt[-2:]
    579     args = tt[:6] + (fraction,)

~\anaconda3\lib\_strptime.py in _strptime(data_string, format)
    357     if not found:
    358         raise ValueError("time data %r does not match format %r" %
--> 359                          (data_string, format))
    360     if len(data_string) != found.end():
    361         raise ValueError("unconverted data remains: %s" %

ValueError: time data 'm' does not match format '%m/%d/%y %H:%M'
```

I would appreciate any help. Thanks in advance!

Comment: Can you show us a very small example dataframe with rows that can reproduce your error?

Comment: Check your input, there is an m in the datetime string but strptime doesn't recognize it as a valid date/time.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use [`to_datetime`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.to_datetime.html) with your format and `errors='coerce'` for convert not matched values to missing values `NaT`:

```
potus['appt_start_date'] = pd.to_datetime(potus['appt_start_date'],
                                          format=date_format, 
                                          errors='coerce')
```

Comment: Much appreciation. It worked. I always learn some new and cool trick with pandas with your comments. Thank you Jezrael.

Comment: So when I ran the code and displayed the df again, all my values for the appt_start_date column were converted to NaT. Could this mean that I have made the wrong strftime format to pass into to_datetime function as an argument?

Comment: @OscarAgbor - So first with same data working and then not?

Comment: yeah it is very strange. It worked then not. I am trying it again and it is returning the column as only NaT values. I have not changed anything from your original code. Very perculiar

Comment: @OscarAgbor - If restart IDE not help?

Comment: i restarted it. Thank you it worked :) . Sorry for the confusion.